# imagemagick jaggy edges with clipping path

Tags: imagemagick, clip

We updated to the latest version of ImageMagick (ImageMagick-7.0.3-1-Q16-x64-dll) and since then, all images that have a clipping path are jaggy. I cannot for life of me figure out why. I can't remember the old version that we had used to previous to this but the images all had smooth edges on white backgrounds when they were clipped. Here's an example of a script I'm using:

```
convert -density 400x400 \
-profile "C:\Step_Assets\Profile\sRGB_profile.icc"  \
"C:\Users\programmer\Desktop\Testing Imagemagick\original\852067A.tif" \
-flatten  \
-alpha transparent \
-clip-path "silo" \
-alpha opaque -trim -density 72x72 -strip -resize 600x600 \
-gravity center -extent 600x600 +repage -quality 96 \
"C:\Users\programmer\Desktop\Testing Imagemagick\converted\852067A_d.jpg"
```

This is a slimmed down version of a script that generates 4 different size images.

Here's an example of an image that ran thru imagemagick and was clipped:

[image: imagemagick clipped image]

any help appreciated!!!

Comment: What was the previous version you used ? can you show what it looked like then ?

Comment: Previous version was ImageMagick-6.9.2-3-Q16-x86-dll.

Comment: ![Conversion of old image vs conversion of new image](http://nimmot.net/imagemagick/old-vs-new-conversion.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

By adding **+clip** before the **-strip** option i was able to solve it.

convert -density 400x400 \
-profile "C:\Step_Assets\Profile\sRGB_profile.icc"  \
"C:\Users\programmer\Desktop\Testing Imagemagick\original\852067A.tif" \
-flatten  \
-alpha transparent \
-clip-path "silo" \
-alpha opaque -trim -density 72x72 **+clip** -strip...